# Why is "device-width" not working on Chrome for Android?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am referencing this guide on how to "[make a mobile friendly website.](https://www.thesitewizard.com/css/mobile-friendly-responsive-design.shtml)" It does not seem to be taking effect on my Chrome-Browser for Android.

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width ;
  zoom: 1.0 ;
}
```

I added this to my Django static files in `app.css` and it is definitely on the website because I can see it using Chrome Developer Tools on my laptop. However, when I use my Android phone (Galaxy S8 if that matters) it does not fit to screen.

I also have this in my `base.html` that my entire site is using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Some follow-up questions: Do I need to empty the cache on my phone? How can I use Chrome Developer Tools on my phone to inspect the CSS of a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From What I understand that is just a css based replacement for the following HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I would suggest using the above meta tag in your `index.html` In addition too this you will still need to add `@media` queries to actually make it responsive for the various screen sizes.

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575px)  ... 

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767px)  ... 

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991px)  ...
```

In addition to the above PX based breakpoints, you can also use DPI-based break points: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

But to actually answer your question about the remote debug console I don't know about anything else that workes as well as the Chrome Developer tools for mobile (Ctrl + Shift + M)

Comment: Thank you! I had not heard of DPI-based break points. I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: For some reason, this is not exactly working on mobile. I have an AJAX 'DataTables that is going off the screen pretty consistently... I'm surprised there isn't a really easy solution for this! But I get it is a complicated subject. Upvoting b/c this improves desktop layout a bit for sure.

Answer (score 0):

use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

Comment: I have that also unfortunately. I'll update to reflect.